# Creating elegant if statements

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the following set of `if` statements:

```
<?php

if (!empty($sn1link) && !empty($sn1)) {
    echo('<a href="'.$sn1link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$sn1.'</button></a>');
}

if (!empty($sn2link) && !empty($sn2)) {
    echo('<a href="'.$sn2link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$sn2.'</button></a>');
}

if (!empty($sn3link) && !empty($sn3)) {
    echo('<a href="'.$sn3link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$sn3.'</button></a>');
}

if (!empty($sn4link) && !empty($sn4)) {
    echo('<a href="'.$sn4link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$sn4.'</button></a>');
}

if (!empty($sn5link) && !empty($sn5)) {
    echo('<a href="'.$sn5link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$sn5.'</button></a>');
?>
```

I would like a more elegant way of combining these `if` statements. I've tried `else if` but obviously this would only display the first `if` statement that returns `TRUE` whereas I'd like to return every `TRUE` statement. I don't think a `switch` would work either.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not iterate and use arrays?

```
foreach($sn_array as $link => $text):
    if(!empty($link) && !empty($text)) echo ...;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Great. Works perfectly. I should have thought of this to start with.

Comment: @Ryan, This will produce undesired collisions.

Comment: @Alexander Why will it? Not being funny here, would just like to understand better.

Comment: @Ryan, empty or same `$link` strings (i.e. `''`) will undoubtedly led to the same keys replacing themselves remaining only the last added one. If you need to keep the original elements then this is a big problem, otherwise it is just fine for the purpose of your needs.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for the explanation. In 99% of the cases, the strings will not be empty so I think this should work just fine. Thank you for the clarity though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a for loop with variable variables:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    $link  = 'sn'.$i.'link';
    $button = 'sn'.$i;

    if (!empty($$link) && !empty($$button)) {
        echo('<a href="'.$$link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$$button.'</button></a>');
    }
}
```

Comment: While that would work, it's generally considered bad practice to use variable-variables.

Answer (score 0):

you should make it a loop, where the values are in an array. then only one if, and one echo statement are needed to accomplish the same thing.

```
$snList = array($sn1 => $sn1Link, $sn2 => $sn2Link, $sn3 => $sn3Link);

foreach ($snList as $name => $link) {
   echo('<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$name.'</button></a>');
}
```

you don't even need the if statement, because if the values don't exist, you simply don't add them to the $snList array in the first place.

```
$snList = array();
$snList[$key] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much more elegant this would be but you could use a function like:

```
    function getButtonContent($link, $content) {

        if (!empty($link) && !empty($content)) {
            echo('<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank"><button class="lbutton-content">'.$content.'</button></a>');
        }
    }

    getButtonContent($sn1link, $sn1);
    getButtonContent($sn2link, $sn2);
    getButtonContent($sn3link, $sn3);

etc....
```

If you have this in more than on place or have something similar the function approach might help.